# Accessing parent window from facebook iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, iframe, width

I'm trying to access in **jQuery** to the browser width from an iframe inside facebook (app).

The issue is we're not allowed to access to a parent element of an iframe, so I'm trying to get it from a `$.post()` query where jQuery writes the window with, but since it's a HTTP query, there's no window parameter loaded.

So I'm wondering if we can access to the `screen` parameter. I mean by this, if there is any browser parameter by default, so I can resize my body page.

For example, if **`parent.window.width < 500`**, I want my **`body`** width to be set as `500`.

Thanks for helping me, I appreciate !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The iFrame domain must match the parent domain to be able to access it directly.

If I remember correctly, Facebook offer a "Fluid" option for the canvas size (which sets the iFrame width to 100%). If Facebook still offer this, you could place your content in a container div and add onLoad and onResize events with jQuery in the iFrame document. You could then set the size of the container based on the iFrame document size.